# IE10 Javascript "Function Expected"

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer

This code is giving me a `SCRIPT5002: Function expected` error:

```
var callIt = function(func) { func(); }
```

WHY!? It's like it's trying to do type checking or something

EDIT: use case

```
var callIt = function(func) { func(); }
function nextSlide() {
    var fn = currSlide ? currSlide.hide : callIt;
    currSlide = setupSlides[++slideIdx];
    fn(currSlide.show());
}
```

DOH!

Comment: and what are you passing into `callIt` as a parameter?

Comment: a function. `callIt` is to serve as a tmp function to replace a jquery animation function. Eg: `(currentSlide ? currentSlide.hide : callIt)(nextSlide.fadeIn)`

Comment: @MarkusOrreilly: Show the call to `callIt`, that's where the error is.

Comment: Make sure you are calling it as: `callIt(MyFunction)` and not `callIt("myFunction")`
Also, for clarity, make sure to end your statement in a semicolon so an anonymous function afterwards doesn't attempt to call the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code:

```
fn(currSlide.show());
```

...**calls** `currSlide.show()` and passes the return value from calling it into `fn`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

since the return value of `show` is not a function, you get the error. You may have meant:

```
fn(function() { currSlide.show(); });
```

---

Note, though, that you have a problem here:

```
var fn = currSlide ? currSlide.hide : callIt;
```

If `currSlide` is truthy, you'll get a reference to the `hide` function, but that function is *not* in any way connected to `currSlide`. If you call it later, it's likely to fail because it's expecting `this` to mean something specific.

If you can rely on having the features from ECMAScript5 (so, you're using a modern browser other than IE8 and/or you're including an "es5 shim", you can fix that with `Function#bind`:

```
var fn = currSlide ? currSlide.hide.bind(currSlide) : callIt;
```

Or if you're using jQuery, you can fix it with jQuery's `$.proxy`:

```
var fn = currSlide ? $.proxy(currSlide.hide, currSlide) : callIt;
```

Both of those return a new function that, when called, will call the target function with the given `this` value.

If you're not using ES5 or jQuery, well, this would do it:

```
var prevSlide = currSlide;
var fn = prevSlide ? function(func) { prevSlide.hide(func); } : callIt;
```

...but at that point I suspect stepping back and reevaluating might be in order.